# Get dynamically created variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I have created with php several javascript array which are called as follows:

```
pricesArray_230
pricesArray_350
...etc...
```

I now want to access these arrays, but I have no clue how to include the dynamic part.

My code right now, which is not working:

```
newPrice = pricesArray_+productId+[currentSimpleProduct][0];
```

Where productId is the dynamic part and represents 230, 350, or any other number.

Do any of you have an idea how to dynamically call these arrays?

Comment: Why don't you simply put them in a big (sparse) array or in an object?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid `eval`, assuming that `pricesArray_*` are *global* variables, you can use:

```
window['pricesArray_' + productId][currentSimpleProduct][0]
```

Better yet, update your dynamically-generated code so it creates an object or array instead of variables:

```
var pricesArrays = {
    '230': {...},
    '350': {...},
    // etc
}
```

Comment: That's an object actually (not an array) but +1!

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the browser, and the variable is in the global scope, you can use bracket notation like:

```
foo = window['pricesArray_'+productId[currentSimpleProduct][0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `eval`:

```
newPrice = eval('pricesArray_' + productId)[currentSimpleProduct][0];
```

However, eval can be problematic, so I suggest using an object instead. This will require you to change your PHP code to output something like this:

```
var arrays = {
    product230 : [], // array here
    product350 : [] // array here, etc.
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
newPrice = arrays['product' + productId][currentSimpleProduct][0];
```